# How to search and delete html link in sql using regex and command line UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, sed, grep, html-parsing

Looking to our Magento application, i found several unused links in cms pages, so, I exported the table, i have a sql file, and now I wanna replace/delete those links using command line.

I'm trying to use a regex pattern to do it, but my regex experience is based on playing in this [regex interactive web](http://www.regexr.com/).

There are MANY links in these pages, but i just wanna delete those who link to `domainname.com` and `domainname.es`, so, which the best way to do it whit these kind of links:

```
<a title=\"CRADLE 1-SLOT SER USB CK30/31 NOTES\" href=\"http://domainname.com/terminales-intermec-accesorios/3813-cradle-1-slot-ser-usb-ck3031-notes.html\"></a>
```

or

```
<a title=\"CRADLE 1-SLOT SER USB CK30/31 NOTES\" href=\"http://domainname.es/terminales-intermec-accesorios/3813-cradle-1-slot-ser-usb-ck3031-notes.html\"></a>
```

I was trying to do something with `grep` and/or `sed` but with my regex

`grep “\w+\=+\\\"+\w+\:\/\/+(s|\w)+(s|\.)+(s|plusexpress)+\.(\/a>)\b”`

it doesn't work, so, any help is welcome!

EDIT:

THe sqlfile has just strings like this:

```
d style=\"text-align: center;\">&nbsp;<img src=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/media/small_image.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"117\" height=\"117\" /><br /></td>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: center;\">\r\n<p>PSU WALL AC CV30 NOTES</p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>Univ Supply Circ 5P 12V 50W FW5012 RoHS.<br /></td>\r\n<td>Requires AC power cord (CAIEC) Will not power heated display element.&nbsp;</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: left;\">\r\n<p><a href=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=7797\" target=\"_blank\">VE011-2013</a><a title=\"WALL MOUNT CABLE PROTECTOR CV30  NOTES\" href=\"http://domainname.es/termina-accesorios/3982-wall-mount-cable-protector-cv30--notes.html\"></a></p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: center;\"><img src=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/media/small_image.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"117\" height=\"117\" /><br /></td>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: center;\">\r\n<p>WALL MOUNT CABLE PROTECTOR CV30 NOTES<a title=\"WALL MOUNT CABLE PROTECTOR CV30  NOTES\" href=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/ve011-2013\"></a></p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: left;\">\r\n<p><a href=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=3681\" target=\"_blank\">VE011-2011</a><a title=\"ADAPTOR MOUNTING PLATE CV30 \" href=\"http://domainname.es/termina-accesorios/3981-adaptor-mounting-plate-cv30-.html\"></a></p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: center;\"><img src=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/media/small_image.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"117\" height=\"117\" /><br /></td>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: center;\">\r\n<p>ADAPTOR MOUNTING PLATE CV30</p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td><br /></td>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: left;\">\r\n<p><a href=\"http://www.anotherdomain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=3680\" target=\"_blank\">VE011-2006</a></p>\r\n</td>\r\n<td style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\"><img title=\"VE011-2006 MOUNT KIT BRACKET WALL CV30\" src=\"h
```

Comment: you are working with html or assimilate so you also should assume lot of variante for a generic pattern. reply will be not bullet proof with non HTML oriented product like grep/sed/awk

Comment: Regexp are not the right tool for this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0):

assuming link are on a 1 line (and only this, so delete the whole line) and based on your sample

```
grep -v 'href=\\"http://[^/"]*(domainname.com|domainname.es)/' YourFile
```

it remove all the line with this href link what ever the tag is (you could filter to `<A` tag if needed)

Comment: No, links are not in a different line at time, they come from a string stored via wysiwyg in a column in magento cms_pages (a mysql table), so, i have a big string and inside this string i wanna replace the whole HTML tag starting in "<a..." and endind "></a>"

I guess, the good regex would be something like:

search "<a" followed for whatever text, plus inside this text search for "domainname.com" followed for more text and ends in "></a>"

Comment: I think i'm close to find it:
    (<\/a>)+(<)+(a)+\s+((.*?))([domainname])+(.*?)(.html\\\"><\/a>)

I'm using `sed` to get the output of this regex in another file but now i need how to test if `sed` is working fine, with `diff` i don't understand the output

Comment: try maybe a `comm -3 OldFile NewFile`  or `-13` instead of `diff` in this case . Also with sed, use another separator than `/` in `s///` (ex: `s:::`) to allow `/` as character in your regex without escaping it